# How to write Google Cloud Functions in TypeScript with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write the code for a Google Cloud Function in TypeScript. The idea is that the source repo will have handler functions defined for multiple Cloud Functions, each in a different file, and some code shared by all handlers. I can compile my sources with tsc, but I need to webpack them to generate a single `index.js` that Cloud Functions will load. So I need webpack to merge the handlers into a single file.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Here's the code for one handler from `src/TheHandler.ts`:

```js
import { EventFunction } from "@google-cloud/functions-framework";

export const TheHandler: EventFunction = (
  message,
  context
) => {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(context);
};
```

This compiles to JavaScript without a problem.

Now I feed it into webpack. Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const files = fs
  .readdirSync("src")
  .filter((item) => item.match(/\.ts$/))
  .map((file) => `./src/${file}`);

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: files,
  externalsPresets: { node: true },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

This results in `dist/bundle.js` to be empty as confirmed by webpack output:

```
asset bundle.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
./src/TheHandler.ts 612 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.50.0 compiled successfully in 1937 ms
```

Is this a module format issue or webpack trying to bundle everything before ts-loader compiles `src/TheHandler.ts`? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `libraryTarget: "commonjs2"` to `output` in `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

As you found, you need to set [`libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget) in order to build a webpack bundle that can itself be imported by another module outside the webpack build (e.g. from cloud functions).

You might have an easier time (and better developer experience in terms of reliable HMR) using [webpack-cloud-functions](https://github.com/hedgepigdaniel/webpack-cloud-functions/) (of which I'm the author). It abstracts away much of the configuration you need to use webpack with cloud functions, including configuring the `libraryTarget`.